# Make all additional threads return from a method using Interlocked.Increment

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety

I need to ensure a method is executed only by one thread at a time. Contrary to what most of the synchronization primitives do, I don't need other threads to wait, I want them to return from the method immediately if it is already executed by another thread. Additional complexity is that the method uses `async/await` calls.

I implemented it using `Interlocked.Increment`. I tested in a simple test scenario and it seems to be working. However, I'm not sure, is it a correct implementation and will it work in all cases? Or maybe there is a simpler way to achieve the same goal?

```
private int _threadsCount = 0;

public async Task Method()
{
    if (Interlocked.Increment(ref _threadsCount) > 1)
    {
        Interlocked.Decrement(ref _threadsCount);
        return;
    }

    try
    {
        await DoWork();
    }
    finally
    {
        Interlocked.Decrement(ref _threadsCount);
    }
}
```

Comment: Code review is for code that you are confident works.  Currently, your question reads as if you don't know if it works or not.  If you have tested the method and believe it to work, I suggest rewording your question to say that, or you risk the question being closed as off topic.

Comment: @forsvarir well I tested it and it works, but one never can be sure in the multithreading scenarios... So this kind of questions should be posted to StackOverflow? I was in doubt, but since I had the code, I decided to post it there.

Comment: I think it's on topic here, but you should include that you have tested it and believe it to work in your question.  The current wording suggested that you didn't really know one way or the other if it was correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, your code should work. Though the first part can be simplified to:

```
if (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref _threadsCount, 1, 0) != 0)
{
    return;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

> Or maybe there is a simpler way to achieve the same goal?

You could also use [Monitor.TryEnter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.threading.monitor.tryenter(v=vs.110).aspx) instead:

```
private object _lock = new object();

public async Task Method()
{
    if (!Monitor.TryEnter(_lock)
    {
        return;
    }

    try
    {
        await DoWork();
    }
    finally
    {
        Monitor.Exit(_lock);
    }
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't use `Monitor` with `async`-`await`, even when you're not blocking. The reason is that `Exit` has to be called from the same thread as `Enter` or `TryEnter`, but `await` can move execution to another thread.

Comment: Good point... I wasn't aware of that.